# How can I use .less compiler with angular 2?

Tags: angular, webpack, less

How can I use .less compiler with angular 2? I have done the npm install  for less and less-loader, but I am stuck in the configuration of webpack to compile a bunch of .less files?

Comment: If you are using `angular-cli` for compiling, you may configure it in `angular-cli.json` file, read more [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-css-preprocessors)

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/less-loader Its mentioned here

Comment: hey if you use angular-cli using less it is as easy as running this command ng set defaults.styleExt less and if you want to config your webpack using angular-cli you can use ng eject command and you will be able config your webpack

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project you can do

```
ng new project_name --style less.
```